# Points on lines with prescribed distances to each other

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry

Given three lines $l_a, l_b, l_c$ in $\mathbb {R}^3$ and three positive numbers $a, b, c>0$ I would like to find points $A, B, C$ on $l_a, l_b, l_c$ respectively, such that the side lengths of triangle $ABC$ are $a, b, c$. I know that this problem can not always have a solution and the solution is not necessarily unique but in my case I know that there is a solution and I know that I can start with a good initial guess. One possibility is to do an iteration, however I wonder if there is an analytical solution.

At the end my goal is to estimate the pose of three lines from three intersections with a sphere. This problem can be reduced to the problem above.

The 2-dimensional case would also be interesting. Furthermore I am also interested in the case where the three lines $l_a, l_b, l_c$ intersect in one point.

Comment: Suppose the lines are (1+2r,0,3r), (-1+4s,5s,0) and (0,1,t), and the side lengths are 6,7,8.  Then it’s easy to write out the equations and eliminate t, and the result convinces me that there’s no analytical solution:  the equation for r would be at least of 8th degree.

Answer (score 2):

This is just confirming and illustrating @MattF.'s example of
three skew lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Solving the equations yields
$8$ $(r,s,t)$ solutions for a $(6,7,8)$ triangle: $4$ imaginary, and $4$ real.

---

[image: TriOnLines]

 

<sup>Black point: origin. Three lines: red, blue, green,
$(1+2r,0,3r), (-1+4s,5s,0), (0,1,t)$. Four solution $\triangle$s.</sup>

---

Although, as he says, there is (in general) no analytical solution,
numerical solutions are easily computed.